# Xcode Cloud can't find GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-cloud

I try to `build` my iOS app (made with Flutter) with `Xcode cloud`, all is fine until I get this error:

```
Build input file cannot be found: '/Volumes/GoogleService-Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file 
as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
```

The file is added to the git repository under `ios/Runner` and if I try to build using `Xcode` I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by moving the file to `ios/Runner` and adding a reference to it using xcode